# how to know which broker published message when connected to multiple brokers

Tags: client, mqtt

I've got some javascript code that connects/subscribes to two brokers by using 2 different client objects.  My problem is how to tell where a message came from in my onMessageArrived.  I'm getting messages, but I can't tell which broker was the source.  Is there a way to know this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't

The work around is to have 3 `onMessageArrived` functions:

```
client1.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrivedOne;
client2.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrivedTwo;

function onMessageArrivedOne(message) {
  message.broker = 1;
  onMessageArrived(message)
}

function onMessageArrivedTwo(message) {
  message.broker = 2;
  onMessageArrived(message)
}

function onMessageArrived(message) {
  //do what you need
}
```